# Vuebootstrap b-alert is not showing dynamic message from axios call response variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I used vue bootstrap for styles, I am trying to create a user register form. When user submit form, axios will send post call to api and if the call is success, api will return success response or if there is an error api will return error message in response. I am trying to capture the response and provide an alert on webpage.
The current code showing alert message for first couple of times and then no message is shown on alert. I am trying to learn how bind data in vue, thanks.

```
<template>
<div>
  <div  class="container1">
  <b-card
    text-variant="Dark"
    header="Please Register"
    header-text-variant="white"
    class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded"
    header-class="card-header"
  >
      <b-form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" v-if="show">
        <b-form-group id="input-group-2" label="User Name" label-for="input-2"
                      style="text-align: left">
        <b-form-input
          id="input-3"
          v-model="form.name"
          placeholder="Enter User name"
          required
          ref="name"
        ></b-form-input>
          </b-form-group>
      <b-form-group
        id="input-group-1"
        label="Email address"
        label-for="input-1"
        style="text-align: left"
      >
        <b-form-input
          id="input-1"
          v-model="form.email"
          type="email"
          placeholder="Enter email"
          required
          ref="email"
        ></b-form-input>
      </b-form-group>

      <b-form-group id="input-group-2" label="Password" label-for="input-2"
      description="Password should be more than 8 characters."
      style="text-align: left">
        <b-form-input
          id="input-2"
          v-model="form.password"
          placeholder="Enter Password"
          required
          ref="password"
          type="password"
        ></b-form-input>
      </b-form-group>
      <b-button @click="showDismissibleAlert=true"
                class="submit_button" type="submit">Submit</b-button>
    </b-form>
  </b-card>
    </div>
  <div>
    <b-alert
      v-model="showDismissibleAlert"
      variant="danger"
      dismissible
      fade
      :show="showDismissibleAlert"
      @dismissed="showDismissibleAlert=false"
    >
      {{ showalert }}
    </b-alert>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400;600&family=Poppins&display=swap');

.container1 {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10%;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.card-header {
  background-color: #12858b;
}
.submit_button {
  background-color: #12858b;
}

.form-control::placeholder {
  opacity: 35%;
}

</style>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  el: '#showalert',
  name: 'LoginForm.vue',
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        showalert: '',
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        showDismissibleAlert: false,
      },
      show: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async onSubmit(event) {
      const path = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/register';
      axios.post(path, {
        user_name: this.form.name,
        email: this.form.email,
        password: this.form.password,
      })
        .then(() => {
          const result = 'Success!';
          console.log(result);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.response) {
            // alert(error.response.data);
            this.showalert = error.response.data;
            console.log(error.response.data);
          }
        });
      event.preventDefault();
      this.form.name = '';
      this.form.email = '';
      this.form.password = '';
      this.show = false;
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.show = true;
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the field data is generated from form, after updating variables it worked. below is what it looks after I added.

```
<b-alert
      v-model="showDismissibleAlert"
      variant="danger"
      dismissible
      fade
      @dismissed="showDismissibleAlert=false"
      class="error-alert-message"
    >
      {{ form.showalert }}
    </b-alert>
```

&

```
.catch((error) => {
          if (error.response) {
            this.showDismissibleAlert = true;
            this.form.showalert = error.response.data;
            this.form.image1 = false;
            this.image2 = true;
            console.log(error.response.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for you is right here in the [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/alert#v-model-support).

> Do not use the show prop when using v-model.

Comment: I removed :show prop in b-alert, but no message is displayed in alert box.

Comment: What about set `showDismissibleAlert` to `true` in the `catch` block?